# Using the with cURL command-line tool on Mac, What can I do to this script to ask it to fetch stock data which comes back WITHOUT commas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, bash, csv

```
cd documents/quoteUpdate
while true
do
   curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl&f=sl1c1p2pt1"
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cURL command-line tool on Mac, What can I do to this script to ask it to fetch stock data which will replace commas with NO SPACES](http://superuser.com/questions/865309/using-curl-command-line-tool-on-mac-what-can-i-do-to-this-script-to-ask-it-to-f)

Comment: @JdeBP - This question has an accepted answer, the other one doesn't (and is newer).  I voted to close the other one as a duplicate rather than this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` to edit quotes.txt. This example changes all commas to a space character (s/,/ /g). A backup of the original file is named quotes.txt.bak.

```
cd documents/quoteUpdate
while true
do
   curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl&f=sl1c1p2pt1"
   sed -i '.bak' 's/,/ /g' quotes.txt  # replace commas with spaces
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Suspectus that was very gracious of you to answer that so quickly. I will try that out. May I revert back to you If I have any issues.Thanks Chris (Scotland)

Comment: I just happened to stumble across the post at that time. By all means let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Hello suspectus, I tried that additional piece of code in the terminal to get the numerical stock data to pull without the commas. However when I run the executable it wont run properly nor will it produce produce a txt file with the data on my quoteUpdate folder on my desktop. Chris-Dormans-MacBook-Pro:~ chrisdorman$ /Users/chrisdorman/Desktop/quoteUpdate/runNow ; exit;
/Users/chrisdorman/Desktop/quoteUpdate/runNow: line 4: curl-o: command not found
sed: quotes.txt: No such file or directory
UPDATED:
Do I have to add the hashtag replace with commas with spaces into the code?

Comment: Hi Chris - the curl command is not found - just after `line 4:` in your comment `curl-o` should be `curl -o` or is that a typo?

Comment: could you please have a look at my short screen capture with audio on Vimeo. This explains the issue which is arising. Thank you in advance of your help again. https://vimeo.com/116850154

Comment: Hi Chris would you be good enough to accept the answer? The question  asked has been answered. To preserve the standards of the site its best that any assistance I give should be addressed to subsequent question posed on the Unix and Linux site. Thanks,