# How do I DELETE a comma and a space from a numeric string using a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, sed, bash-scripting

Folks, I have asked this question *5 times* on here and have received 5 separate bits of code from super users that have all *failed.

Problem: I have stock information being brought back into a txt file from Yahoo Finance's API.

The issue is: numerical strings brought back from such *have commas and spaces* in them which is a nightmare to delimit in Excel. Excel wants to split 670,000,000 into 3 separate values and split such across 3 separate columns which is a joke.

How do I get 670,000,000 to look like 670000000.

Who can solve this puzzle which so many have failed. This Script below is the latest to fail.

```
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
 curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl,avxl&f=nsj2l1"
 sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 5
done
```

Comment: @Optichip your solution is the closest yet (without trying the 3 solutions below in this). It took the number and stripped the commas and spaces which is superb. HOWEVER when I asked the script to bring back another info perimeter for shares float ( bang the commas came back for this new perimeter )I want to kill the commas and spaces indefinite irrespective of what numeric string I ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cURL command-line tool on Mac, What can I do to this script to ask it to fetch stock data which will replace commas with NO SPACES](http://superuser.com/questions/865309/using-curl-command-line-tool-on-mac-what-can-i-do-to-this-script-to-ask-it-to-f)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got a solution for you....

```
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
  curl  -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl,avxl&f=nsj2l1"|sed -e 's/,/_/1' -e 's/,/_/1' -e's/\(.*\),/\1_/' -e 's/,//g' -e 's/_/,/g' > quotes.txt
  echo UPDATED:
    date
    sleep 5
  done
done
```

Give that a try....  You can append data to your quotes.txt file by simply changing the > quotes.txt to >> quotes.txt

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head this **ugly** solution should do the trick. Replace your sed line by the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\"";OFS="\"";}{gsub(",","",$5);$5=","$5;print $0}' quotes.txt > UPDATED_quotes.txt
```

I'll update this post if I find a more elegant answer.

Comment: that removes the last comma from the line as well.

Comment: @Optichip What do you mean last comma?

Comment: The last comma, before the 508.08 (Current stock price) is removed as well when I run your command.

Comment: @Optichip my understanding was that it was a requirement (eg: 678,365,000,508.08 should be transformed as 678365000508.08)

Comment: Yes, maiki, that _is_, what the asker said -- commas to be removed. But that's not, what he _meant_ :-) The last number must remain intact.

Comment: @MikhailT. don't know because he was really specific *"How do I get 670,000,000 to look like 670000000."*. In addition, leaving the latest comma won't solve his problem when importing the csv to excel (last column will still be split in two)

Comment: Folks, I need this process to work with about 250 separate stock securities not just for google. This has to work multi latterly.

Comment: and for all numeric strings brought back beyond this example. There is about 30 technical indicators per stock. I CANT HAVE COMMAS ever

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting from Yahoo! is data in [CSV-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). The format is too complex for bash (or even sed or awk) to properly parse in a one-liner. (Being full Turing-machine capable, any of the tools *can* do it, it will just not be pretty.)

Your immediate problem with the above script is that `sed` is not given any input to work on, so your script hangs (after `curl` finishes), because `sed` awaits on `stdin`. You, probably, want to append "quotes.txt" to `sed`'s current command-line:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta' quotes.txt
```

But, once you deal with that, you'll still be unhappy, because the `sed`-command does not parse CSV-data as such. You'll want a CSV-processing tool of some kind -- search for a CSV-parsing package written for your favorite scripting language. In case of [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/), [CSV-parsing is available](http://wiki.tcl.tk/38945) as part of [tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/home), for example.

Finally, if you don't really need to properly handle all possibilities of a CSV, but only ensure, the numbers in the *third column* are understood by Excel, you can cheat with something like:

```
curl -o - -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl,avxl&f=nsj2l1" | \
    awk -F, '{
        sub("^ *", "", $3);  # Start with 3rd field by stripping leading spaces
        for (i = 4; i < NF; i++) # Append other fields to 3rd - but the last one
            $3 = $3 $i;
        print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $NF
    }'
```

The above call sends data directly from `curl` into `awk` (bypassing the intermiediate file-creation). If you need the data in a file (such as for Excel to load), redirect `awk`'s final output into it:

```
.... awk ..... > quotes.csv
```

Nothing bash-specific in this example, BTW -- any shell would do. Note, that this `awk`-script only modifies the third-column (appending subsequent "columns" to it except the very last -- the NF). Note also, that it will fail, if one of the corporation-names ever has a comma in its name. If this is a problem for you, it can be avoided by using quotes (") instead of commas to find the numbers that must be merged together... But best of all, again, would be to treat the data as the proper CSV by using CSV-aware extension for your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl instead of sed

```
perl -pe 's/,(?=\d{3}(?![.]))//g'
```

replace comma (followed by tree digits with no trailing a decimal point) with nothing.

Oh, just saw you also want the spaces trimmed

```
perl -pe 's/,[ ]+/,/g;s/,(?=\d{3}(?![.]))//g'
```

This should be used in the framework in place of 'sed', like

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  clear
  date
  curl -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl,avxl&f=nsj2l1"|\
    perl -pe 's/,[ ]+/,/g;s/,(?=\d{3}(?![.]))//g'| tee quotes.csv
  cat quotes.csv| sed -e 's/,/\t/g'> quotes.xls
  sleep 5
done
```

Did you know that excel will readily open a csv file "as is" 
if it has commas replaced with tabs and has the '.xls' extension.

Comment: Does not auto update every 5 seconds this code for some strange reason and does not do what im looking for

Comment: @ChrisDormani It does now (after edits).